# XML- Android CheckBox Widget

Tags: android, xml

Thanks a lot.I am beginning of android.I am trying a CheckBox button.I make a small project. See my project photo:

1.why the list of CheckBox is not same position, it's like a random?

Check my Xml code:

2.I am using android:layout_marginTop="30dp", android:textSize="20dp", Is it perfect rules in declaretion? It will be same support all devices?

[image]

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wonton Soup " 
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Egg Drop Soup " 
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="French Fries " 
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

Again a lot of Thanks.

Comment: `android:textSize="20dp"` for TextViews you should use sp instead of dp

Comment: Can you please tell me in which layout you are putting all checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Text length is not same for all Checkbox. Put value in the max length filed of the text view.  Like

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

    android:maxWidth="125dp"
    android:text="French Fries /Testsatrs"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:text="French Fries "
    android:textSize="20dp" 
    android:maxWidth="125dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="French Fries " 
    android:maxWidth="125dp"
     android:textSize="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.why the list of CheckBox is not same position, it's like a random?

You are centering your CheckBoxes with `android:layout_gravity="center"`. Observe that the bounds of each CheckBox is centered in its parent.

Perhaps what you are instead expecting is something along these lines:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <CheckBox ... />

    <CheckBox ... />

    <CheckBox ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

The CheckBoxes would then appear left-aligned inside a centered box that wraps their width.

> 2.I am using android:layout_marginTop="30dp", android:textSize="20dp", Is it perfect rules in declaretion? It will be same support all devices?

I'm not sure what you mean with this question, but there are two possible problems:

1. If the layout doesn't scroll, the layout may extend beyond its boundaries on devices with smaller screens. A simple solution may be to wrap the whole layout inside a ScrollView.
2. Using DPs for text is not recommended as the user may have set a preference for text scaling: `android:textSize="20sp"`

   Alternatively, you may want to use one of Android's preset TextAppearances, for instance: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`

Comment: thanks a lot @Paul Lammertsma!! Can i declare direct android:layout_marginTop="30dp"? this 30dp size will be same size all devices?? if is not declare direct then what i do perfect use??

Comment: [DP are device-independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP), so the size will be the *same physical size* on each device. If you wish to have a larger margin on large devices, such as tablets, then I suggest you define a different dimension using a resource qualifier; for that [I suggest reading this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  Put all checkboxes into LinearLayout .

Step 2. Set all checkbox properties,

```
          android:layout_gravity = "left"
```